# Find the limit $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ where $k\in\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, power-series, exponential-function

If $k=0$, then ${e^z-1\over z}=\sum_{n\ge0}{z^n\over (n+1)!}$. So. $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z}{e^z-1}=1$.
Now if $k\ne0$, then $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}{e^z-1\over z}=\sum_{n\ge0}{(2k\pi i)^n\over (n+1)!}$, **now can it be zero?** If this limit is non-zero then the required limit will be a finite complex number, if not then the answer will be $\infty$.
**So, my question is- Can $\sum_{n\ge0}{(2k\pi i)^n\over (n+1)!}$ be $0$?**
Thanks for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, if $k\neq0$, $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}z=2k\pi i\neq0$ and $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}e^z-1=0$,$$\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}\frac z{e^z-1}=\infty.$$

Comment: Basically, I faced the problem to check whether the function $f(z)={1\over e^z-1}$ is an open map or not on the region $\{z|\operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$. But it has poles. I cannot apply open mapping theorem. Is it an open map?

Comment: Every non-constant analytic function with a connected domain is open.

Comment: It is not analytic on the given region, it has poles st $2k\pi i, k\ne0$

Comment: It is still analytic. The existence of poles doesn't destroy that.

Comment: Is it analytic at the poles?

Comment: That makes no sense. The poles are not part of the domain.

Comment: Why? $2k\pi i\in\{z|\operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}, k\ne0$.

Comment: But $\frac z{e^z-1}$ is undefined at those points. So, the domain of your function is actually$$\{z\in\mathbb C\,|\,\operatorname{Im}z>0\}\setminus\{2k\pi i\,|\,k\in\mathbb N\}.$$